# Cakephp country helper

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

I have a problem with this helper : https://github.com/kshakirov/cakephp-lang-helper

This helper give me this error and I don't find why :

```
Fatal Error

Error: Call to a member function input() on a non-object
File: \app\View\Helper\LangHelper.php
Line: 670
```

Comment: that plugin is over a year old - what version of cake are you using?

Comment: Looks like a dependency issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the problem is that LangHelper overrides the parent `__construct` method, preventing Cake from setting up the Helper correctly. Change LangHelper's `__construct()` to the following:

```
public function __construct(View $View, $settings = array()) {
    parent::__construct($View, $settings); 
    $this->mapper = $this->parseLangHeaders();
    $this->langCode = $this->findLangCode();
    $this->countryCode = $this->findCountryCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate the `FormHelper` in the `AppController`?

```
App::uses('FormHelper', 'View/Helper'); // Don't forget this one in Cake 2.x

class AppController extends Controller
{
  public
    $helpers = array('Form');
}
```